# How to modify length of ArrowHelper in three.js

Tags: javascript, vector, three.js

I'm using ArrowHelpers to model and display forces on an object. The length of the vector represents the magnitude of the force. 
But: modifying the length of my arrowhelper does not seem to have any visible effect. When viewing the scene, all of my ArrowHelpers appear to have the length that was assigned to them during construction. The direction of the vector is properly updated. What am I doing wrong? Here's my code:

```
// construction:
ARROW_GRAVITY = new THREE.ArrowHelper( dir, origin, length, 0xDD3377 );
SCENE.add( ARROW_GRAVITY );

// updating scene:
ARROW_GRAVITY.position.copy(BULLET.position);
var dirGrav = new THREE.Vector3( 0, -1, 0 );
dirGrav.normalize(); // not necessary in this case, I know
ARROW_GRAVITY.setDirection(dirGrav);
var gravForce = PROJ_MASS * 9.8;
ARROW_GRAVITY.length = gravForce;
ARROW_GRAVITY.updateMatrix();
console.log(ARROW_GRAVITY.length); // works as expected (returns gravForce)
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/helpers/ArrowHelper) for how to change the length of `ArrowHelper`.

```
arrowHelper.setLength( length );
```

Note: there are additional optional arguments.

three.js r.93

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried both "arrowHelper.length = "  and "arrowHelper.setLength()". In both cases  the length remains at the initial length. When retrieving the length, the correct value is returned, but it isn't correctly visualized in the scene. Even if I set the length to zero, nothing happens.

Comment: WestLangley, you are absolutely right, I was just confused by the presence of the seemingly spurious 'length' property of ArrowHelper (which apparently has nothing to do with its actual length). Thanks for your trouble.

Comment: `ArrowHelper` does not have a `length` property.  You can add properties to objects in Javascript, which is what you did. The property you added is not used.

Comment: Now I get it! Sorry, I'm quite new to JavaScript. Thanks for educating me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to WestLangley's answer, `.setLength()` with parameters works as expected:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(2, 3, 5).setLength(4);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0x101000);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var dir = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
var arrow = new THREE.ArrowHelper(dir, scene.position, 2);
scene.add(arrow);

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(4, 4));

var clock = new THREE.Clock();
var time = 0;

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  time += clock.getDelta();
  arrow.setLength(Math.cos(time) * 0.5 + 1.5, 0.5, 0.1);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/93/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you both are right. Somehow it didn't work for me at first, probably due to another issue. What still puzzles me though, is that myHelper.length always returns 'undefined'. So it seems ArrowHelper has a 'length' property which doesn't do anything. You can set it and retrieve it, but it has nothing to do with the actual length (which is indeed set by using setLength()).

Comment: @user1770718 You're free to look at how it works under the hood [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/35ae830a7c4544582ed2759e5b18c5d6ef37c6d9/src/helpers/ArrowHelper.js#L99).